# increasing sequence in $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I want to prove that a (countable) increasing sequence in $\omega_1$ converges to some point. Here is my idea:

I first try to find the limit point. We know any point in the increasing sequence (say $x_n$) is also a point in $\omega_1$, which means only countably many points in $\omega_1$ is smaller than (or equal to) $x_n$. So the set of points in $\omega_1$, which is also smaller than some point in the sequence, is countable. $\omega_1$ is uncountable and well-ordered, so we can take the complement and get a minimum point. I claim the minimum point after the sequence is the limit point.

However, I am not sure whether the minimum point after the sequence can be an open singleton set, since I have asked some related questions, like the following one:

> For each $\alpha\in\omega_1$ note that $\{\min(\omega_1\setminus I_\alpha)\}$ is an open set where $I_\alpha:=\{x\in\omega_1:x\le \alpha\}.$

So how can I proceed my proof (i.e. show that the minimum point can not be an open singleton) or my proof is fundamentally not correct?

Comment: +1 This does sound like a homework question, but OP has shown substantial thought on the problem and has shown where s/he is stuck. Certainly don't close for off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and let $\alpha$ be the minimum element of $\omega_1$ greater than all $\alpha_n,$ as you described it (which exists, if we assume, as I suspect you are assuming, that a countable union of countable sets is countable). First, note that $\alpha$ cannot be the minimum element of $\omega_1.$ We show now that $\alpha$ is not an immediate successor.

> Suppose that $\alpha$ *is* an immediate successor--that is, there is some $\beta\in\omega_1$ with $\beta<\alpha$ such that there exists no $\gamma\in\omega_1$ with $\beta<\gamma<\alpha.$ By definition of $\alpha,$ we know that $\beta$ is not an upper bound on the sequence. Hence, there is some $n\in\omega$ such that $\beta\le a_n.$ Since we have an increasing sequence, then $\beta<a_{n+1},$ and by definition of $\beta,$ we must have $\alpha\le a_{n+1}.$ But then $\alpha$ cannot be an upper bound of the sequence, either, contradicting our choice of $\alpha.$

The upshot is this: given any $a,b\in\omega_1$ with $\alpha\in(a,b)$--that is, with $a<\alpha<b$--there will *always* be some $c\in\omega_1$ with $a<c<\alpha,$ so that $(c,b)$ is a strict subset of $(a,b),$ and still a neighborhood of $\alpha.$ Hence, $\{\alpha\}$ is *not* open.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this material. Can you explain in some less advanced (more intuitive) sentences?

Comment: Apologies for the first version of the answer. It was patently incorrect, in addition to being overly advanced. Please see my corrected and improved answer, and let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: May I ask another question about this sequence and its limit? If we construct a countable sequence by letting a1 be the smallest element of omega_1, a2 be the smallest element of omega_1 excluding a1, ...., and an be the smallest element of omega_1 excluding a1, a2,..., an-1. We also find b, the limit of this sequence as the method above described. Do you think such subset {a1, a2,..., an,..., b} counts as an initial segment of omega_1, which is also a "copy" (homeomorphic) of omega plus 1? Thanks

Comment: It certainly does. Let's call the subset $S.$ To confirm it as an initial segment of $\omega_1,$ you need only show that if $\alpha,\beta\in\omega_1$ with $\alpha<\beta$ and $\beta\in S,$ then $\alpha\in S.$ In the case that $\beta\neq b,$ this is fairly trivial, and not too much harder when $\beta=b.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha = \min(\omega_1 - \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}} [0,a_n] )$. (Existence of $\alpha$ is guaranteed by axiom of choice.) To prove $\alpha$ is a limit point of $\langle a_n\rangle$, we only prove following proposition:

> For each $\beta<\alpha$, there is $n$ s.t. $\beta< a_n<\alpha$.

Note that $\{(\beta,\alpha] : \beta<\alpha\}$ is a local basis of $\alpha$. (That is for each open set $V$ containing $\alpha$, there is $\beta<\alpha$ s.t. $(\beta,\alpha]\subset V$.)

Its proof is simple: if there is $\beta<\alpha$ s.t. $\beta\ge a_n$ for all $n$, then $\beta\in \omega_1 - \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}}[0,a_n]$ so $\alpha\le\beta$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how is your alpha different from the alpha in the situation I asked: For each α∈ω1 note that {min(ω1∖Iα)} is an open set where Iα:={x∈ω1:x≤α}, where the alpha can be proved to be an open singleton set, since if alpha can form an open singleton set, we can not say our sequence converge to alpha any more.

Comment: @12345 Yes. $\{\min(\omega_1\setminus I_\alpha)\}$ is open singleton set. However, $\min(\omega_1\setminus I_\alpha)$ is *always* successor ordinal, and the limit of (strictly) increasing ordinal sequence is limit ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

it is a known fact that ω1 is sequence-compact.
because:

1.the cofinality of ω1 is not smaller then ω,because if it was ,ω1 woulde be a countable union of countable sets.

2.every ordinal has a max limit-ordinal smaller-or-equil to it.and between them are a finity number of ordinals.(if not,we get a dicreasing sequence).

so we can build a converging sub-sequence,by looking at some up-bound,that is small enoght that there is an sequence-element between it and the limit-ord from 2,and checking if:

**i**. the sequence converges to it.

**ii**.there are infinity elements between it and its limit by claim 2,and then a converging sub-sequence.(infinity element in finity ords.

**iii** .if not,look at the sub-sequence that all elements are small then thet limit ordinal,and do it over again.

the loop will stop in finity step(if not,we ger a decreasing sequence of limit ordinals),and so there are infinity elements in the finity*finity ordinals we looked at.

in a increasing sequence,we get that the hole sequence converges,because **ii** is alwyas right,and because of that **i** also

Comment: The cofinality of $\omega_1$ is *equal* to $\omega$ *if and only if* $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable sets, no?